# Changing the Dynamic Default Broker Config using Java AdminClient

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently I am changing the default broker configurations in my kafka cluster using the `kafka-configs.sh` script.

```
./kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server <bootstrap_server>  --entity-type brokers --entity-default --alter --add-config max.connections=100
```

The above command would set the default value of max.connections configuration to 100 in all my brokers of the cluster. I would like to achieve the same through Java.

I tried using the alterConfigs method in the AdminClient class. Using this method I am able to set the configuration value, but this value getting at the broker level.

Due to this I would have to execute the alterConfigs for each and every broker in the cluster which is not scalable.

Could anyone help me with changing the default broker configuration using AdminClient class similar to what I was doing with the shell script.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the code below to set configs at broker-default level:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    Map<String, NewPartitions> newPartitions = new HashMap<>();

    ConfigResource configResource = new ConfigResource(ConfigResource.Type.BROKER, "");
    ConfigEntry entry = new ConfigEntry("max.connections", String.valueOf(100));
    AlterConfigOp op = new AlterConfigOp(entry, AlterConfigOp.OpType.SET);
    Map<ConfigResource, Collection<AlterConfigOp>> configs = new HashMap<>(1);
    configs.put(configResource, Arrays.asList(op));
    try (Admin admin = AdminClient.create(props)) {
        admin.incrementalAlterConfigs(configs).all().get();
    }
```